# Show jquery value in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm approaching a problem I had yesterday from a different angle slightly but my jquery/js skills are basic to say the least.

I have a div that I want to increase the transform value of every 5s:

```
<div style="transform: translateX(0px);" id="slide_images">
    ...
</div>
```

and I am using this jQuery code to attempt to do it but I can't work out how to get the showpixels value to work in the HTML:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var pixelArr = ['-1100px','-2200px','-3300px','-4400px'],
            counter = 0,
            timer = setInterval(function(){
                pixelTimer(pixelArr[counter]);
                counter++
                if (counter === pixelArr.length) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }, 5000);

        function pixelTimer(showpixels) {
            $("#slide_images").css("transform", "translateX(showpixels)");
        }
    });
});
```

I know its something very simple but for some reason my brain is having a hard time with this. Put simply I want to change the style="transform: translateX(0px);" line in the HTML to decrease by -1100px every 5 seconds. Help please!

Comment: You need to concatenate the string and the variable: `$("#slide_images").css("transform", "translateX(" + showpixels + ")");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#slide_images").css("transform","translateX(showpixels)"); //just a string
```

should be

```
$("#slide_images").css("transform","translateX(" + showpixels + ")"); //using the numbers
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :).